# How to use list comprehensions for this code

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to use a list comprehension to achieve the same results as below. Can anyone help?

```
s1 = "one two three four"
s2 = "five six seven eight"

my_list = []
l1 = s1.split()
l2 = s2.split()
my_list.append(l1)
my_list.append(l2)

print(my_list)
```

It outputs:

```
[['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'], ['five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight']]
```

Comment: `[x.split() for x in (s1, s2)]`?

Comment: Or skip the list comprehension and just use `[s1.split(), s2.split()]`?

Comment: I don't know, just use `[s.split() for s in [s1, s2]]` or `list(map(str.split, [s1, s2]))` please read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

use a list of all the strings you want as

```
lst_of_s = [s1,s2,s3]

result = [i.split() for i in lst_of_s]
```